# How to identify external javascript, broken images and css files from wordpress theme using php / laravel

Tags: php, wordpress, laravel

I would like to indentify external javascript, broken images and css from wordpress themes by using laravel and php.

Please let me any laravel package or php code for it.

Thanks,
Amol Rajhans

Comment: have you googled this question?

Comment: Yes. But I didn’t get what I was looking for.